# count distinct number for multiple table fields in one queryset django

Tags: python, django

I need to count sum of distinct values of for each column(aa, bb, cc in this case) from a table with one queryset. If I do this:

```
x = a_table.objects.filter(m = m_number)
.annotate(a=Count('aa', distinct=True))
.annotate(b=Count('bb', distinct=True))
.annotate(c=Count('cc', distinct=True))
.values_list('a', 'b', 'c')
```

When I print x, I got:

```
<QuerySet [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)]>
```

How do I get result like this within one queryset:

```
a=4
b=4
c=4
```

Comment: `x=a_table.objects.values(fieldname).annotate(the_count=Count(fieldname))` considering a_table is your models class

Comment: Thanks! @0decimal() My table has may be 10 columns. I only need to calculate total counts of distinct value in 3 columns. If I do this in 3 queryset like this:

Comment: Thanks! @0decimal() My table has maybe 10 columns. I only need to calculate total counts of distinct values for 3 columns. If I do this in 3 separate queryset like this: a = a_table.objects.filter(m=m_number).values('aa').distinct().count() and so on, it would be OK. Now I need to put three queryset into one. How would I do this? Your comment above still need to write 3 separate query sets right?

Comment: `x=a_table.objects.annotate(Count('aa'), Count('bb'),Count('cc'))` try it.